# Chrome Extension: create tabs sequentially

Tags: google-chrome-extension, async-await

I'm trying to open tabs sequentially with a Chrome Extension but even when using promises they all fire at the same time.

Here is the code:

```
scrape();
async function scrape()
    {
        for (a = 0; a < 10; a++)
           {
            // I SET VARIABLES HERE BUT NOT RELEVANT FOR THE QUESTION
            console.log('open tab');
            await CreateTab ({ url: search_url, active: false }, myvariable);
            console.log('tab done');
        }
    }

 function CreateTab (createProperties, sid_meta)
    {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        {   
           chrome.tabs.create(createProperties, tab => 
           {
              // do some stuff here

           });
           resolve();
        });
    }
```

As you may guess, all 10 tabs are opened at once while I would like to open them one by one and only open a new one if the previous one is closed.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Laurent

Comment: Resolve inside the callback.

Comment: ah-ah, so simple and so true :) Thanks, it works perfectly now!